# Is there any options in Android to separate keyboard for integer and for float numbers

Tags: android

I have text field where user need to write some numbers. Is there any options in Android to separate keyboard for integer and for float numbers ( for integer keyboard to have only digits, for float to have digits+ comma and point) ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
myEditText.setKeyListener(DigitsKeyListener.getInstance(false,true));
```

This will lock the input of the `EditText` to digits, points and commas.
Setting the second boolean to `false` will allow only integers (no points and/or commas).

Take a look [here](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/text/method/DigitsKeyListener.html) for the full documentation.

Comment: Wow My Samsung galaxy S2 (language set to german) is persistently refusing to show a comma oO ... I tried tons of ways to fix this - using InputMethod (keeping the dot pressed doesnt show a comma, as it does for some), using your suggestion but none seems to work.

Comment: @Zainodis Am I right to assume you used the setKeyListener method in the way I described above? With the second boolean set to `true`? If so, it won't show a comma because that is not the character for a decimal point. Using a dot or comma as decimal point is purely aesthetic and doesn't change the outcome. In other words, don't worry about it, your code will still work.

Comment: Actually I tried every possible combination of false,true xD ... The thing is --> for instance if you enter a german currency like 20,50€ (meaning 20 Euro and 50 Cent) you can't really do that with a dot, as the dot is the divider for thousands in Germany, so parsing the currency (using the Phones Locale - German in this case) would fail ... Or am I mistaken?

Comment: I wouldn't know anything about using locale for sure, but you could test this yourself pretty easily I reckon. Also, apologies for the late reply, I haven't been on SO for a while.

Comment: yeah I actually did test it and at least on my Galaxy S 2 I can't get it to work - despite trying every possible combination of the above given answer. However we just went with another approach to circumvent that issue.

Comment: Good to hear you worked out a solution. Sorry I couldn't help more.